# Jsoup: Linebreaks in URL cannot be removed

Tags: java, html, jsoup, line-breaks

I'm collecting links from HTML and using jsoup to get the links which I add to a collection. The problem is that I need each link to be on one line so when written to a file it can be parsed line by line.

The input is a WARC record and for each record I want to get all links. 
The getcontentutf8() and getHeaderMetadataItem methods come from a WarcRecord api [found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.digitalpebble.behemoth/behemoth-io/1.1/edu/cmu/lemurproject/WarcRecord.java#WarcRecord.getContentUTF8%28%29).

The code:

```
String baseURL = getHeaderMetadataItem("WARC-Target-URI");
Vector<String> retVec = new Vector<String>();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(getContentUTF8(), baseURL);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    for (Element link : links){
        String newLink = link.absUrl("href").replace("\n", "");
        retVec.add();
        System.out.println(newLink);
    }
```

When writing stdout to file some links get split over two lines, for example:

```
1: http://somelink.com/submit?url=
2: http://someotherlink.net
```

While other might look like this (the way I want them):

```
1: http://somesite.com/submit?url=http://someothersite.com/
```

It looks like it always happens after a `=`.

EDIT: Added more information. Seems like removing both carriage return and newlines fixed some cases. However, now I am encountering tab characters within absolute URLs from jsoup. I checked some source sites and they actually have tabs after href. Seems like there are can be alot of cases to handle. I would like to think that there is a general solution to catching them?

```
<a class="MenuButton " href="/      features"> <em> Features </em> </a>
```

turns into the absolute URL:

```
http://archinect.com/    features
```

Since I store it to file on form `URI \t <list of links>` this will break when I parse it

Comment: To get proper answer sooner please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]. Currently we have no idea about `getContentUTF8()` content. One improvement which you could make is to use `replaceAll("\\R", "")` instead of `replace("\n", "")`. `replaceAll` uses regex, and in regex `\R` represents any line separator, including `\r\n` which is used in Windows.

Comment: `?url=...` is a GET parameter, so it is part of the url and should be written in one line.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you, you are correct. I have added some more information. I hope it is more satisfactory now. I now check for both newlines and carriage return and the first problem is gone. Thank you

Comment: @FredericKlein Yes. That is the way I want it. On one line. The initial formulation was not clear on that. Its changed now. The problem is/was that it came on two lines when printed.